# ASP using variables from previous page in SQL query

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

On my first page I have an array defined as:

```
dim selection
    selection = Array("name", "city")
```

On the following ASP page I'm trying to call to those same variables for an SQL query:

```
dim selection
    selection = array(request.form("name"), request.form("city"))
```

In my SQL query:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * from Users where name='" + selection(0) + "' and city= '" + selection(1) + "'
```

This doesn't work, and I've tried tooling around with it but I can't seem to find a working solution. What am I missing?

Comment: "doesn't work" *how*?

Comment: The query returns no values. I believe I am not calling on the previous page's array correctly?

Comment: You can't post an array like that. check: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/101999-1.shtml
Also for just 2 values you don't need an array, you could use hidden inputs or pass them via query string.
Also be aware of sql injection when exposing a query like that!

Comment: On the first page I do need the array because I've forced 2 SQL columns into the same select box and needed a way to make each column unique. Now that those values are unique [selection(0) and selection(1)] I need to call on them in the next page for yet another SQL query. How would I use hidden inputs to pass them along?

Answer (score 0):

Html forms don't do arrays. The best you're gonna get via `Request.Form()` is a comma-delimited list, and that's if you have multiple form fields with the same name: there is just no way to pass along an entire array "in one piece".

Based on your "I've forced 2 SQL columns into the same select box" comment, I think what you need is something like:

```
<select name='Person' size='1'>
    <option value='NameID1~AddressID1'>John Smith, 123 Main Street</option>
    <option value='NameID1~AddressID2'>John Smith, 345 Elm Avenue</option>
    ...
</select>
```

... which you would handle on the submit end by splitting on the delimiter character:

```
const delimiter = "~"
selection = Request.Form("Person")
If Instr(selection,delimiter) > 0 Then selection = Split(selection,delimiter)
```

Naturally, you need to choose your delimiter character(s) such that there's no chance it'll occur in your option values.